# My POI files are not showing in OsmAnd

Tags: osmand

I have created POI using KML to .obf format,imported it to the SD card storage,also seleted the option 'Any' from POIs settings, but Osmand is not displaying any POIs.
I also imported some city maps(.obf format),which i have downloaded manually, stored in the same folder,OsmAnd is showing the maps properly but POIs. It will be great if someone please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.